# AWS Neptune Notebook: not able to create notebook

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-neptune, graph-notebook

I am trying to create AWS Neptune Notebook I am using AWS Neptune notebook wizard to create a note book,  but it fails to create it. I was able to create it before and suddenly it stopped. I have no change in VPC, subnet and security group.
my security group allows to connect to port 8182. I enabled logs and i see below errors.

```
fatal error: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://aws-neptune-notebook.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/graph_notebook.tar.gz"
fatal error: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://aws-neptune-notebook.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/graph_notebook.tar.gz"

2022-06-22T16:27:28.948-04:00   tar (child): /tmp/graph_notebook.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory

2022-06-22T16:27:28.948-04:00   tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now

2022-06-22T16:27:28.948-04:00   tar: Child returned status 2

2022-06-22T16:27:28.948-04:00   tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

2022-06-22T16:27:33.799-04:00   -bash: line 11: /tmp/graph_notebook/install.sh: No such file or directory
```

when accessing url from logs, it says https://aws-neptune-notebook.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/graph_notebook.tar.gz is moved to another location but i am not sure where and how i should update this url.

Comment: The `aws-neptune-notebook` S3 bucket is located in `us-east-1` region so it will not work with the extra region identifier. The default Neptune Notebook lifecycle is configured to use a region-less URI by default (`s3://aws-neptune-notebook/graph_notebook.tar.gz` should become https://aws-neptune-notebook.s3.amazonaws.com/graph_notebook.tar.gz)

Comment: In the `aws s3 cp` command in your notebook's lifecycle, could you try explicitly specifying the bucket region by adding the `--region us-east-1` option?

Comment: Just checking in - were you able to get the notebooks working OK Jigar ?

Comment: yes, thanks for you inputs, I used custom lifecycle and also I had to use "Access through VPC" option while creating notebook  from AWS console.